# How to insert values in H2-Database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am inserting the data in inMemory database H2 ,while inserting the data i am getting an issue,

Sample program to insert data in inMemory using boot,JPA,H2db

Created Pojo and annotated with JPA annotation

Created data.sql file for queries.

I tried with a number of ways, but still the same exception

POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "fullname" , nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    // NoArgsConstructor , AllArgsConstructor , getter and setter for brevity
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "role_id", updatable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    private String name;

       // NoArgsConstructor , AllArgsConstructor , getter and setter for brevity
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

data.sql

```
insert into roles(name) values('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

Exception:
[image: Spring Boot Exception]

Rest of  exception Stack

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-09 20:28:08.765 ERROR 4916 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Parth/Downloads/parth/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into roles(name) values('ROLE_ADMIN'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ROLE_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into roles(name) values('ROLE_ADMIN') [23502-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.example.parth.ParthApplication.main(ParthApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Parth/Downloads/parth/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into roles(name) values('ROLE_ADMIN'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ROLE_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into roles(name) values('ROLE_ADMIN') [23502-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:38) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:111) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ROLE_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into roles(name) values('ROLE_ADMIN') [23502-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:374) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:187) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 37 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the stacktrace too?

Comment: @Parth Are you sure that you've included `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `h2` dependency in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @Raman Sahasi, yes I have added the dependency  the issue is created by data.sql  when i remove its working fine

Comment: @Tamás Pollák i update my code

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add UUID by using java.util.UUID.randomUUID()
OR
if you are using hibernate 5, below code should work

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue
private java.util.UUID id;
```

id column should have type BINARY(16) in MySQL or it's equivalent in other SQL implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because you do not provide an ID value in your insert statement. And  ID can not be null. You annotated your id field in your entity with generator annotations, but they only work, if you save an entity through JPA. JPA is not involved when you execute a native sql in your script. *So, you have to provide an ID in your insert statement in data.sql.*

This is the important part of your stacktrace, and the cause of the startup failure:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ROLE_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into roles(name) values('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

Comment: Even when I provide ```id``` still I get the error, One more doubt I used ```@GeneratedValue``` so I thought it will automatically will be created